# How can I view the shortest distance between two islands?

Tags: online-resources, maps, islands, swimming, sailing

I wonder whether there exists a convenient way to view the shortest distance between two islands. For example, can some of the commonly used online mapping resources, and if so, how? Ideally, I'd prefer a precise, fast, fully automated method.

I'm posting on Travel.SE as I am looking at the feasibility of swimming or sailing between islands, and the distance between the islands is one of the factors to take into account.

Comment: What is wrong with that? Eyeball it, move your pointers once or twice and you have a reliable distance. What more do you want?

Comment: @Willeke a precise, fast, fully automated method.

Comment: That seems more like a [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) question, though you'd likely need to narrow it down to a particular software package to ask it. You've tagged this question "swimming," and there are likely to be practical considerations for that activity (rocks, cliffs, private property and restricted areas, currents in the water, ship traffic) that would influence the choice of starting/ending points far more than an automated calculation can provide, but specifics on open water swimming routing might be a topic for [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ZachLipton " you'd likely need to narrow it down to a particular software package to ask it". That's the issue, I'm looking for whichever solution is the most convenient. GIS may require more expertise from the OP.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it sounds like you are looking for some software that can do this function. I would suggest asking here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. This is not a travel question.

Comment: @GregHewgill Welcome to Travel.SE, asking for resources is on-topic, and this is not a travel question (see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swimming).

Comment: @ZachLipton yeah, to me the way to find the most exact method automatically would be to download the best vector data for the islands in question available, and then in QGIS using something like Nearest Neighbour (off the top of my head). This will show the distance, but not necessarily the path, which would require another tool.

Comment: Tides, currents and winds will dictate the route between any two points separated by open water.  Thus this fixation on the most accurate minimal point to point distance is naive at best (and that's being charitable). As suggested elsewhere (and IMHO) this is not a travel related question, and belongs elsewhere.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The best I've found so far is Google Maps but it's tedious as one has to find the shortest distance [manually](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Lanai,+Hawaii+96763,+USA/20.8744133,-156.6784887/@20.8560676,-156.7689206,12.5z/data=!4m9!4m8!1m5!1m1!1s0x795536d9a3986425:0xf609afa076d8b8b5!2m2!1d-156.9273193!2d20.8165975!1m0!3e0) by moving points around:

[image]

Comment: Given as a not good enough option in the question, now moved to an answer? Poor quality.

Comment: @Willeke it's still an answer, and not part of the question. SE guidelines state not to mention answers in questions.

Comment: Selecting your own terrible answer? lol

Comment: @eps add your great answer then, I'd be happy to accept it. lol